# suppressing a line feed in a cmd batch / trying to get 2 commands onto 1 line in output file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

did try googling this. Someone said a for loop, which I don't know that well.

These 2 in a cmd batch command file:

```
echo %date% %time% >> "%onedrive%\trackip.txt"
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | Find "Address:" | Find /V "208.67.222.222" >> "%onedrive%\trackip.txt"
```

puts

```
timestamp
ip address
```

on different lines.

I'd like

```
timestamp  [some spaces] IP address
```

each time it runs.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: (please note that `DOS` and the Windows Command Line (`cmd`) are very different things (although they look alike and share most of their commands, they have some major improvements in `cmd`))

Answer (score 0):

Well, for anyone else that needs help, here it is:

```
echo |set /p=%date% %time% >> "%onedrive%\trackip.txt"
nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com | Find "Address:" | Find /V "208.67.222.222" >> "%onedrive%\trackip.txt"
```

Just add

```
echo | set /p=
```

to that first line!? Really!?  That's it?

KUDOS TO:

https://www.techjunkie.com/echo-without-newline/

Comment: you should mention that
1. ***redirection*** `<nul` is faster than piping
2. leading spaces/tabs/non-break spaces will be stripped
3. leading `=`s causes syntax errors